# Updating Rails 4.2 to 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to update a rails app from 4.2 to 5 but see the following error when performing `bundle update`

```
  In Gemfile:
    actionpack

    activerecord-session_store (= 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      actionpack (< 5.2, >= 4.0)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.7.2)

    rspec-rails (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    activeresource (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
      activemodel (< 7, >= 5.0)

    carrierwave (= 1.3.1) was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.5.4, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.7.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-session_store (= 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      activerecord (< 5.2, >= 4.0)

    acts_as_list (= 0.9.19) was resolved to 0.9.19, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.0)

    oink was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
      activerecord

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.7.2)

    thinking-sphinx (= 3.4.2) was resolved to 3.4.2, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "countries":
  In Gemfile:
    countries

    country_select (~> 3.1, >= 3.1.1) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      countries (~> 2.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "geokit":
  In Gemfile:
    geokit (= 1.6.7)

    geokit-rails (= 1.1.4) was resolved to 1.1.4, which depends on
      geokit (>= 1.5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    i18n (~> 0.6)

    activemerchant was resolved to 1.43.3, which depends on
      i18n (~> 0.5)

    money (~> 6.13.8) was resolved to 6.13.8, which depends on
      i18n (<= 2, >= 0.6.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In Gemfile:
    activemerchant was resolved to 1.43.3, which depends on
      json (~> 1.7)

    etsy (~> 0.2.5) was resolved to 0.2.7, which depends on
      json (>= 1.5.0)

    jslint (~> 1.2.0) was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      json

    rdoc (~> 3.4) was resolved to 3.12.2, which depends on
      json (~> 1.4)

    simplecov was resolved to 0.17.1, which depends on
      json (< 3, >= 1.8)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (= 1.3.1) was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
      mime-types (>= 1.16)

    paperclip (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.5.4, which depends on
      mime-types

    rest-client (~> 1.6.7) was resolved to 1.6.14, which depends on
      mime-types (~> 1.16)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    nokogiri

    activemerchant was resolved to 1.43.3, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-session_store (= 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.2, >= 4.0)

    coffee-rails (~> 4.2.2) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0)

    jquery-rails (~> 3.1.2) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.0)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.7.2)

    rspec-rails (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0.5) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "redis":
  In Gemfile:
    redis (~> 3.3)

    resque-scheduler (~> 4.3.0) was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
      redis (< 5, >= 3.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rest-client":
  In Gemfile:
    rest-client (~> 1.6.7)

    chargebee (= 2.2.8) was resolved to 2.2.8, which depends on
      rest-client (~> 1.4)

    easypost (~> 2.7, >= 2.7.1) was resolved to 2.7.3, which depends on
      rest-client (>= 1.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby

    activerecord-session_store (= 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.3)

    bundler (= 1.17.3) was resolved to 1.17.3, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.8.7)

    minitest was resolved to 5.16.3, which depends on
      ruby (< 4.0, >= 2.6)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.2.2)

    rspec-rails (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.2.0)

    sass was resolved to 3.7.4, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "thinking-sphinx":
  In Gemfile:
    thinking-sphinx (= 3.4.2)

    ts-resque-delta (~> 2.0.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      thinking-sphinx (>= 1.5.0)
```

below is the `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '5.0.7.2'
gem 'bundler', '1.17.3'
gem 'etsy', '~> 0.2.5'
gem 'chargebee', '2.2.8'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.6.7'
gem 'mime-types', '>=1.16'
gem 'oauth', '~> 0.4.7'
gem 'packet', '>=0.1.10'
gem 'hash_extension', '>=0.0.4'
gem 'chronic', '>=0.2.3'
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'xml-mapping', '=0.8.1'
gem 'money', '~> 6.13.8'
gem 'ey_config', '~> 0.0.6'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.4.2'
gem 'ts-resque-delta', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'rmagick', '2.16.0'
gem 'hpricot', '~> 0.8.6'
gem 'nokogiri'#, '1.5.0'
gem 'tlsmail', '0.0.1'
gem 'multipass', '~> 1.4.0'
gem 'spreadsheet', '1.0.0'
gem "mysql2", "0.3.18"
gem "rake"#, "10.1.1"
gem 'redis', '~> 3.3'
gem "typhoeus", "~> 0.6.3"
gem 'json'#, '~> 1.7.7'
gem 'gdata-19', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'crack', '~> 0.4.1'
gem 'geokit', '1.6.7'
gem 'geokit-rails', '1.1.4'
gem 'resque', '~> 1.25'
gem 'resque_solo', "~> 0.3.0"
gem 'resque-scheduler', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'rdoc', '~> 3.4'
gem 'diff-lcs', '1.1.3'
gem 'i18n', '~> 0.6'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'jslint', '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'jslint_on_rails', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'haml', '3.1.6'
gem 'liquid', '~> 2.6.1'
gem 'cancan', '~> 1.6.10'
# gem 'devise', '1.0.10'
gem 'will_paginate', :path => './vendor/gems/will_paginate-master'
#, '~> 3.0.7'
#gem 'country_select', '~> 2.2.0'
# gem 'posix-spawn', :git => 'git://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn.git'
gem 'libxml-ruby'#, '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 6.1.0.352'
gem 'exceptiontrap', '1.0.11'
#gem 'exception_notification', '4.4.0'
gem 'barby', '~> 0.6.2'
gem 'chunky_png', '~> 1.3.3'
#gem 'savon', '~> 2.0'
gem 'prestashop_integration', :path => './vendor/gems/prestashop_integration'
gem 'htmlentities', '~> 4.3.3'
gem 'gravatarify', '~> 3.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.2'
#gem 'dalli'
gem 'p3p', '~> 1.2'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'carrierwave', '1.3.1'
gem 'mousetrap-rails', :path => './vendor/gems/mousetrap-rails-master'
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
gem 'iso_country_codes'
gem 'acts_as_list', '0.9.19'
gem 'activemerchant', :git => 'https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant', :tag => 'v1.43.3'
gem "actionpack"
gem "countries"
gem 'easypost', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
gem 'stripe', '3.28.0'
gem 'oauth2', '~> 1.0'
gem 'sass'
gem 'activerecord-session_store', '1.1.0'
gem 'activeresource', '~> 5.0'
gem 'country_select', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
gem 'net-sftp', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.2'
gem 'oink'
gem 'rbnacl', '3.4.0'
gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf', '1.1.0'
#gem 'ar-octopus'
gem 'rotp'

gem 'makara', '~> 0.3.10'

group :development do
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "test-unit"
  gem "jasmine", "~> 1.3.2"
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'autotest-rails-pure', "~> 4.1.2"
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'factory_bot', '4.11.1'
  gem 'minitest'
  gem "mocha"
  gem 'fakeweb'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 5.0.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '~> 2.0.0'

gem 'simplecov', require: false, group: :test
```

Any help on how to fix this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't be specifying all the versions in Gemfile. You are applying constraints that cannot be met. Bundler will find compatible versions for you. Remove the version specifications.

Comment: I'm with Les here. My advice is to *only* pin down versions that are absolutely necessary, and, importantly, to **add a remark indicating why**. If you can, link to a GitHub issue that explains more, as there usually is one, so you can check back in the future to see if that constraint is no longer necessary. By default, Rails will stamp out version locks like this, which is extremely frustrating as it creates the very problem you're experiencing here.

Answer (score 2):

The advice not to specify versions in `Gemfile` is wrong.

You have go through each error and update other gems to versions compatible with rails 5.

An example:

```
  Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    activeresource (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
      activemodel (< 7, >= 5.0)

    carrierwave (= 1.3.1) was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.5.4, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.7.2) was resolved to 5.0.7.2, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.7.2)
```

Installed versions of `carrierwave` and `paperclip` are incompatible with activemodel 5.0, you have to update these two gems to be compatible with rails 5 (activemodel 5.0 precisely)

Same has to be done with other gems that are listed in your message.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I thought that the error for `carrierwave` means that its compatible with  `activemodel >= 4.0.0` which `activemodel (= 5.0.7.2)` is, isn't it?

Comment: Tbh you're right, the message is hard to decipher =.=

`jquery-rails` think this one is causing errors

```ruby
jquery-rails (~> 3.1.2) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.0)
```

Comment: @opensource-developer the problem is because Bundler cannot coerce versions with different degrees of subversions 5.0 , 4.0.0, 5.0.7.2 etc.. Bundler cannot perform transitive comparisons. I suggest to comment carrierwave, paperclip, activeresource. And bundle again. This should install activemodel as per Rails version. Then to reintroduce the commented gems one by one. By removing version number if it still cannot install.